# Decompose $\frac{x^2-2x+3}{(x-1)^2(x^2+4)}$, partial fraction braindead

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

decompose $\frac{x^2-2x+3}{(x-1)^2(x^2+4)}$

the way my teacher wants us to solve is by substitution values for x,

I set it up like this:

(after setting the variables to the common denominator and getting rid of the denominator in the original equation)

$x^2-2x+3= \frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{x^2+4}$

1)Let $x=1$, after plugging in for $x$ I got $2=5B$, or $B=\frac{2}{5}$

2)let the $x=0$, I get $3=-4A+4B+D$, and if I substitute B and simplify I get $D=4A-\frac{7}{5}$. Furthermore, no matter what value I plug in I still end up with two variables and cant seem to find a way to eliminate one. It seems like I have to set it up as the triple system of equations but I just dont know how to apply it here. Would really appreciate if you guys could give me a hint on how to go about it.

Comment: [How to format your questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: On the left side of the equation $x^2-2x+3=...$ , the denominator is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Start with $$\frac{x^2-2x+3}{(x-1)^2(x^2+4)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{CX+D}{x^2+4}$$

Multiply with $(x-1)^2(x^2+4)$ and then insert the special values.

Comment: I did set it up like that, but i keep getting 2 unknowns and have no clue how to go down to one.

Comment: The insert of special values does not always give ALL solutions. What are the equations you got ? Did you get $4$ equations ?

Comment: after making x=1, I've got  B=2/5, then I  did x=0, and got D=4A-(8/5)+3 and im stuck at this point since no matter what value for X i put. i still have D and C as unknowns

Comment: Try to solve the rest using the value for $B$.

Comment: I did, still end up with D and C as unknowns

Comment: Does the teachet allow ONLY the insert, or does he only suggest it as a help ?

Comment: she said, you should only do the x=.. substitution method, otherwise I would have simplified denominator and just did the long division. it seems like we're ought to use system of equations , but i have no idea how to set them up with what i have right now

Comment: $x^2-2x+3=(A+C)x^3+(-A+B+D-2C)x^2+(4A-2D+C)x+(-4A+4B+D)$. Did you get this equation ?

Comment: The solution is $A=-\frac{4}{25}$,$B=\frac{2}{5}$, $C=\frac{4}{25}$ , $D=\frac{19}{25}$.

Comment: You can insert the complex values $-2i$ and $2i$ to get the values $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute $x=2i$, this gives

$\;\;\;-1-4i=((2Ci+D)(2i-1)^2=(-3-4i)(2Ci+D)=(-3D+8C)-(6C+4D)i$

Therefore $8C-3D=-1\;\;$ and $\;\;6C+4D=4,\;$ so

$\hspace{.6 in}16C-6D=-2\;\;$ and $\;\;9C+6D=6\implies 25C=4\implies C=\frac{4}{25}$.

Then $D=1-\frac{3}{2}C=1-\frac{6}{26}=\frac{19}{25},\;\;$ and $\;\;A=-\frac{4}{25}\;$ since $0=A+C$ from the coefficient of $x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

After $B=\frac25$, you may obtain $C$ and $D$ similarly with

$$\frac{x^2-2x+3}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{A(x^2+4)}{x-1}+\frac{B(x^2+4)}{(x-1)^2}+{Cx+D}$$
by setting $x^2=-4$ to get $1=-8C+3D$, $2=3C+2D$, yielding
$C=\frac4{25}$ and $D=\frac{19}{25}$. On the other hand, $A$ can be obtained by examining the limit $x\to \infty$ of above equation, which leads to $A=-C=-\frac4{25}$.